# Django. Unicode decode error, when runserver

Tags: python, django, encoding

When i am trying to `manage.py runserver` my Django project with Python 3.4.1 I am getting this error:
[image]

This error was not occurs in previuse Python 2,7, and Django 1.6.. (And I am not going to reinstall Python to previouse release..)

```
manage.py migrate
```

Works without any issues.. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your machine's name?

Comment: Most likely your machine name contains non-ASCII characters and this it not correctly handled by Django.

Comment: My machine name was "Sławek" which contains polish letter "ł", but when I am changing it, its not working anyway ;/

Comment: Sorry, You were right.. But i changed User name instead of machine name. Now its work all just fine. Thank you!